# Browswes not able to show changes made in .css file

Tags: css, sharepoint, browser

I have made some changes in `Myfile.css` file in my sharepoint project. after making changes to `Myfile.css` file. I right click the file and do "copy to sharepoint root". I see the message in out put window: "Copy to sharepoint root succeeded!"

But when i open the browser and see the page, i could not see changes on page. Then I press F12 and inspect the respective element where i make changes, it shows the old version of my `Myfile.css` file. I could not see the changes that i made in `myfile.css`? why is that?

I guess browsers shows cached page. It did not takes changes from sharepoint.
What i need to do ?

What I need to change in IE, Chroom and Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

If your css file is cached by the server you may try with adding some variable at the end of the css url.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Myfile.css.css?version=1" />
```

Related question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717993/stylesheet-not-updating

Answer (score 0):

try to navigate in incognito mode, may it helps!

Or alternatively clean your browser's cache, and then reload.

Check here how to do it: [link](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-clear-your-browser-cache/)

Even if it not solves the problem, you can know that's not a browser problem! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have stored your css file in the SharePoint hive. Have you checked the validity of your file in there ?

Path for SharePoint 2010
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

Path for SharePoint 2013
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

If you can, you can try an "iisreset" in command line on your server. Juste care, it'll cause an interruption of service (1 min approximately)