# Website is scrolling horizontally on small devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to figure it out why my website is scrolling horizontally on small devices. I have tried to change a lot of css, but still, nothing happens. Would you please have a look at this [My website](http://web-artist.co.uk)

I guess you can inspect my code. If it is something wrong, let me now

Comment: I checked your website out with many different sizes and it seemed fine on all.

Comment: About how much pixels we talk if you say small devices. On my phone everything works fine. So after inspecting it I would say on very small devices `.boxcolumn` can affect the horizontal scrolling because of it's absolut width of `320px`

Comment: how to make it responsive then?

Comment: of course I could check your website, if you're willing to pay my hourly rate of 100$ :D :P

Comment: Try adding overflow-x:hidden; css style in body.

Comment: @AllinOne don't use this `.boxcolumn` stuff. You're still using bootstrap so make realize that `.boxcolumn` design with `.panel`

Comment: @NadirLaskar has your solution.  Just tested and that worked perfectly.  I'd post it as the answer Nadir, you'll get an upvote from me.

Comment: use `max-width:320px` on the `.boxcolumn` so if the screen is smaller than 320px it will shrink automatically so no scroll . or you could use `overflow-x:hidden` /// plus be careful, in your `boxcolumn` ( only place i checked) you have a lot of empty `p` tags. that's not a good practice

Comment: @trav okay, I am adding it as answer if it works for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want any overflow-x in your page you can hide all overflow in the x direction on the html body for a quick solution.

If at any place inside the body you want a `overflow-x` just add the css style 
`overflow-x:auto;` to that element with some defined `max-width` property.

To solve the issue try adding `overflow-x: hidden;` css to the body.

```
body{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the site on multiple sized devices and browsers and it all looks fine.

Be sure you are not looking at a cached version of the CSS, which will make you think that your CSS changes are not having an effect!

See here:
[Stylesheet not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717993/stylesheet-not-updating)

Comment: There is definitely an issue with the view.  It only seems to show up when the view is just under 360px in width.  From that down to 320px, there is a large white space on the right when scrolling.   Had this issue with Chrome a while back, easily something that's over looked.

Comment: I tested it on the smallest device I could find to hand - an iphone 5c (320 px) and it was loading as expected.

Comment: Just did the same, tested it on multiple devices and I'm totally still seeing that good ole white space.  Except when applying Nadir's fix.