# CSS file not registering changes on apache24 localhost

Tags: html, css, apache, localhost, inspect-element

I'm running a local server (apache24) to try and learn html. I've run into a few problems with this and never understood where I went wrong. But today I went into inspect element while I was on the page, directed myself to sources and clicked on the css file. Evidently something was wrong as it did not mirror my actual css file:

[image: The server css file]

The file in inspect element:
[image: Inspectio Elementio]

This is making it really difficult to learn html using the server. I don't know where to start to fix the problems. I have tried restarting the server and it didn't work. I've had this problem for a while with the server, but I only discovered the part with Inspect Element today. Please help.

Comment: Disable cache when the dev tools open, it is an option under the Network tab

Comment: Try doing a [hard refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate) - ctrl + f5 as it will force the browser to redownload all it's cached files

Comment: Press Ctrl + F5

Comment: What dev tools? I am new to this whole server ding dong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717993/stylesheet-not-updating

Comment: Ctrl + F5 worked. Thanks,

Comment: @Morpheus is talking about this http://nimb.ws/EDMaUP