# Style.css file directory

Tags: php, html, css, directory

I'm creating a website in html / css and was working on 'folder organisation' as I'm also learning php..
To put all pages, php and css in the same folder I create on folder called 'Pages'.

[image: Main folder]

First, I put it in my style.css file. As directory was changed, I also changed it in my main.php code :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Pages/style.css" />
    <title>Test site</title>
</head>
```

And here is my doubt :

In the style.css file, I use as background image one jpg image which is in the 'Img' folder.

I modified the path in the css file like this :

```
background: url('../Img/Contact-picture.jpg') no-repeat;
```

But it doesn't work... The image is not loaded when before it was working !
And second thing I didn't understand is, if I remove **Pages/** in the head part of the main.php file, it loads style.css file normally even if it's in the Pages folder...

Could you help me to understand how is it possible please ?

Thank you for your help,

Jerry

Comment: look into the console and see if you have an error

Comment: Answer found : Mamp cache wasn't reloading all files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717993/stylesheet-not-updating