# I can't see the changes I made in Hostinger but I can in Netlify

Tags: html, css

I uploaded the same file I did to hostinger, to netlify but they look very different. The changes I made to the CSS are reflected in Netlify but not in Hostinger. ¿What can I do?

Netlify: https://64825c771640f80c0466b14b--gleaming-kataifi-5a0bf8.netlify.app/criteriosdiv.html

Hostinger:https://matezapatitos.online

File: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1k_0MqIG_xRY3EBaGKmwAMSdWSHm6C0Nc?usp=sharing

Please help me, it is my first project and I don't even know what to try first.

Comment: hope this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718406/21832849